# Caching JWKS from Identity Provider using Azure API management for validating JWT

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

The code below validates JWT token by downloading JWKS every time it validates each request following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT)

```
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Error: expired token or invalid token" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
        <openid-config url="https://IdentityProvider/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
        <audiences>
            <audience>aud id</audience>
        </audiences>
    </validate-jwt>
```

My question is how to cache the JWKS from the example link below to avoid downloading it every time, and without hard-coding the JWKS, since it is rotated regularly.

https://demo.identityserver.io/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks

https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc/certs

Any code example and links for caching and validate JWT would be appreciated.

Below seems relevant but not a complete example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-cache-by-key

**Update**

Just to be clear, I want to cache the contents from JWKS of the links above to improve performance.

Comment: Have you referred to https://github.com/toddkitta/azure-content/blob/master/articles/api-management/api-management-howto-cache.md?

Comment: thx, will have a look, and let you know

Comment: The old UI is not available. This is the current one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-cache

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the below sample [referred from here](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Generate%20Azure%20Relay%20Token.policy.xml) if that helps !

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <!-- Add your wcf relay address as the base URL below -->
        <set-backend-service base-url="" />
        <!-- verify if there is a relaytoken key stored in cache -->
        <cache-lookup-value key="@("relaytoken")" variable-name="relaytoken" />
        <choose>
            <!-- If there is no key stored in cache -->
            <when condition="@(!context.Variables.ContainsKey("relaytoken"))">
                <set-variable name="resourceUri" value="@(context.Request.Url.ToString())" />
                <!-- Retrieve Shared Access Policy key from  Name Value store -->
                <set-variable name="accessKey" value="{{accessKey}}" />
                <!-- Retrieve Shared Access Policy key name from  Name Value store -->
                <set-variable name="keyName" value="{{accessKeyName}}" />
                <!-- Generate the relaytoken key -->
                <set-variable name="relaytoken" value="@{
                    TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                    string expiry =  Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + 3600);
                    string resourceUri = (string)context.Variables["resourceUri"];
                    string stringToSign = Uri.EscapeDataString (resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
                    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)context.Variables["accessKey"]));
                    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
                    string sasToken = String.Format("SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}",
                    Uri.EscapeDataString(resourceUri), Uri.EscapeDataString(signature), expiry, context.Variables["keyName"]);
                    return sasToken;
                    }" />
                <!-- Store the relaytoken in the cache -->
                <cache-store-value key="relaytoken" value="@((string)context.Variables["relaytoken"])" duration="10" />
            </when>
        </choose>
        <!-- If the operation request uses json format, convert it to XML - Azure Relay expects XML format (based on WCF) -->
        <set-body template="liquid">
            <!-- set your body transformation here -->
        </set-body>
        <!-- Create the ServiceBusAuthorization header using the relaytoken as value -->
        <set-header name="ServiceBusAuthorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>@((string)context.Variables["relaytoken"])</value>
        </set-header>
        <!-- Set the content type to application/xml -->
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/xml</value>
        </set-header>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
    <!-- If the operation responses uses json format, convert it from XML - Azure Relay will return XML format (based on WCF) -->
        <set-body template="liquid">
            <!-- set your body transformation here -->
        </set-body>
        <!-- Set the content type to application/json -->
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Comment: cache look up and store might be relevant. I want to cache the contents from JWKS of the links to improve performance. But I cannot find a full example for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Azure API Management service has built-in support for HTTP response caching using the resource URL as the key (https://github.com/toddkitta/azure-content/blob/master/articles/api-management/api-management-sample-cache-by-key.md). What you could do is to set the openid-config url as an operation and control caching by yourself. Another approach could be by introducing an own caching service.

Comment: Caching reponse is not what I want for this case. I want to cache the contents from JWKS of the links to improve performance. But I cannot find a full example for my case.

Answer (score 0):

APIM will not download open id config for every request. It's downloaded, cached and automatically refreshed periodically, every hour if I recall correctly.

Comment: Do you have the links to your info?

Comment: This link https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc/certs has not cache-control that tells when it is expired. How do I invalidate the cache in this case when the JWK has changed?

Comment: I don't think it's documented anywhere explicitly. cache-control headers are not respected, once fetched data is used for one hour, and then refreshed. To rotate keys you need to make two step rotation: first add new key, and then later remove old key when all tokens signed by it have expired. Also make sure to not have "kid" claim in your tokens, because only single key will be used if its matched by "kid"